# Add the "picture-" suffix to all images when uploading to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using this in my WordPress theme `functions.php` to sanitize all images filenames when uploaded:

```
function sa_sanitize_special_chars ($filename) {
    return remove_accents( $filename );
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'sa_sanitize_special_chars', 10);
```

Now, I need also to add the "picture-" prefix to all images when upload too. How can I do that (in functions.php)?

Comment: I've never used wordpress, but couldn't you just add a second filter that preprends 'picture-' to all the images? Something like `function add_prefix($filename) { return 'picture-' . $filename; }`

Comment: Do you mean prefix, not suffix?

Comment: why not leave the image filenames alone and just put them into an `images/` subdir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will work for you

```
function sa_sanitize_special_chars ($filename) {
$f=remove_accents( $filename );
return 'picture-'.$f;
}
```